# AWS API Gateway, "HTTP status regex" in "Integration Response" cannot match any string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Some background info: my setting is  `browser -> api gateway -> ec2 (using spring mvc)`.
I want to return http status other than 200. After having lot of search in google, I know that I have make some configurations on api gatway. And the followings are my configurations:

1. In `Method Response`, add http status 400
2. In `Integration Response` -> `HTTP status regex`, add `.*httpStatus":400.*`
3. In ec2 (using spring mvc), I always return http status 400 with the following json as response body (for testing)

   > {
   >    "errorMessage": "{\"errorType\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestId\":\"12345\",\"httpStatus\":400,\"message\":\"you got error\"}"
   >   }

However, when I test the api (using the "test" button in api gateway), it still return http status 200. (I expect it should be 400)
When I change the regex to `.*400.*` , it return http status 400 as expected.
When I change the regex to `.*httpStatus.*` , it return http status 200. (I expect it should be 400)

Why can't the regex `.*httpStatus":400.*` recognize my json? Even I simpler the regex to `.*httpStatus.*`.
But the regex `.*400.*` can recognize the int 400 ...

PS: I never forget to deploy the api after any changes on api gateway

Here is the log

```
Execution log for request test-request  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /graphql  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method request path: {}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method request query string: {}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method request headers: {}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method request body before transformations: null  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Endpoint request URI: http://awseb-e-e-AWSEBLoa-1OSQBKG0O3J75-968940376.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/graphql  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=kymhygbqwa, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_kymhygbqwa}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Endpoint request body after transformations: null  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage":"{\"errorType\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestId\":\"12345\",\"httpStatus\":400,\"message\":\"you got error\"}"}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Endpoint response headers: {date=Wed, 13 Jul 2016 15:38:22 GMT, server=Apache-Coyote/1.1, expires=0, transfer-encoding=chunked, access-control-allow-headers=Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-frame-options=DENY, access-control-allow-methods=POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, pragma=no-cache, access-control-allow-origin=*, access-control-max-age=3600, x-content-type-options=nosniff, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, connection=keep-alive, cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method response body after transformations: {"errorMessage":"{\"errorType\":\"Bad Request\",\"requestId\":\"12345\",\"httpStatus\":400,\"message\":\"you got error\"}"}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method response headers: {Content-Type=application/json}  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Successfully completed execution  
Wed Jul 13 15:38:22 UTC 2016 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing one key element:

*For HTTP and AWS integrations, the error pattern is matched against the **HTTP status code** of the integration response. For Lambda "invoke" integrations, the error pattern against the the "errorMessage" field in the response.*

You will need to use the response status code from your SpringMVC endpoint to control the API Gateway response.

For reference, this nugget of wisdom is buried in section 5.b [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html):

See also, a blog post on some of the finer points of error mapping [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/error-handling-patterns-in-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I think you only need to change your regex a little.

In my case:

Lambda:

```
// scores should be numeric
if(isNaN(event.body.score) || isNaN(event.body.maxScore)){
  throw new Error('[400] Score and maxScore should be numbers! For example: 8 
  or 8.5');
}
```

Integration Response:
^[400].*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an express application and have used api gateway infront of it with http integration. To return status code from my application instead of `200 OK` , I have simply added the http status code returned by the error handler of my application to the http status regex in integration response section and it works fine. Make sure your application properly handles error.
[image]